# User Flair image with the site icon in large instead of the gravatar

Tags: feature-request, flair

Hello,

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair says that the data will not be provided anymore, only those images. These images consist of a huge gravatar and only a small icon for the site.

I'd like an image without gravatar but with a large site icon in its place. To me it seems to make more sense to stack those flair boxes with the different site icons instead of repeating my gravatar again and again.

Comment: This is a good idea. Maybe especially for the majority of users who use the default "gravatars".